# HMACSHA512 in Spring OAuth2 doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, hmac

can you help me with my code? I am trying to implement OAuth2 in Spring Security for jwt authentication on my website. I have implemented AuthorizationServerConfig and ResourceServerConfig, and some SecurityConfig where I have declared beans. One of the beans is access token converter.

Here is my implementation:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigner(new MacSigner("HMACSHA512", new SecretKeySpec("secret_password".getBytes(), "HMACSHA512")));
    return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
}
```

Token is generated but when I try call some api with this token I got this error in postman:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Cannot convert access token to JSON"
}
```

When I replace this line:

```
jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigner(new MacSigner("HMACSHA512", new SecretKeySpec("secret_password".getBytes(), "HMACSHA512")));
```

with this line:

```
jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("secret_password");
```

Token generation and also authorization works as well. But it use default HS256. Can you tell me how to fix my code to work it with HS512? Thanks.

Comment: @dur I also tried your second advice and I use this new MacSigner("HMACSHA512", new SecretKeySpec("secret_password".getBytes(), "HMACSHA512")) as new variable and set it to signer and also verifier and I think it works :) but just additional question ... if it is a good procedure?

Comment: Why do you think that is not a good procedure?

Comment: BTW: I already answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475573/spring-oauth2-change-default-signing-algorithm). Do you think, that your new question is a duplicate of your old question? I could copy your (now working code) to my answer, if you like it. I didn't add some code, because I couldn't test it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring OAuth2 - Change default signing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475573/spring-oauth2-change-default-signing-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

to make your algo change to 512
you need to set both server / resource JwtAccessTokenConverter setVerifier to the same as what setSigner do, e.g:

```
jwtAccessTokenConverter.setVerifier(MacSigner("HMACSHA512", SecretKeySpec("secret_password".toByteArray(), "HMACSHA512")))
```

remember: IS BOTH need to set

Answer (score 0):

We can implement HMACSHA_512 algorithm by adding java-jwt dependency.

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupid>com.auth0</groupid>
<artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle Dependency

```
implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.0'
```

**Generate JWT token**

Step 1: Build header information

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("alg", "HS512");
map.put("typ", "JWT");
```

Step 2: Construct key information

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");  //secret key
```

Step 3: We generate jwt token by defining registration and custom declaration and combining header and key information

```
String token = JWT.create()
.withHeader(map)// Setting Header information 
.withIssuer("SERVICE")//Setting load signatures is who generates, for example, servers
.withSubject("this is test token")//Setting the theme of load signature
// .withNotBefore(new Date()) / / set the load definition before any time, and the jwt is not available.
.withAudience("APP")//Audiences who set payload signatures can also understand who accepts signatures
.withIssuedAt(nowDate) //Set the time when the payload generates the signature
.withExpiresAt(expireDate)//Setting the expiration time of load signature
.sign(algorithm);//Signature
```